# background-size not having any effect on background-color

Tags: css

I need an element to have full width, but not its `background-color` property. I tried setting the `background-size` property but it's not having any effect.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav></nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: 80% 100%
}
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Background size does not affect a solid colour background, you will need to use multiple elements or pseudo elements to create that effect (or a single pixel colour image that repeats)

Comment: The [documentation for `background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) states "The background-size CSS property specifies the size of the element's background image.".

Comment: change this `background-color: black;` with this `background-image: linear-gradient(black,black);` and you will have what you want

Comment: If you insert background-image and play with the background-size you will notice that it tiles your image to that size but still fills the whole area. Since a color is the same at no matter the scale, the background-size property does not affect the background-color property.

Comment: My bad for not reading the doc, the name `background-size` implies that it is the size of the element's background. And thanks for the `linear-gradient()` workaround.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It is not working... https://jsfiddle.net/kv2ahoa1/1/

Comment: because you don't have to forget the repeat ;) https://jsfiddle.net/kv2ahoa1/2/